# $τ_1\subseteq τ_2$ and $β_1\in B_1$ then $\forall x\in X$, $\exists β_2\in B_2$ such that $x\in β_2\subseteq β_1$

Tags: general-topology

Let $ B_1$ and $B_2$ be basis for the topologies of $X$ $τ_1,τ_2$, then the below are equivalent.

$i)$ $τ_1\subseteq τ_2$

$ii)$ for every $x\in X$ and for every $β_1\in B_1$ such that $x\in β_1$,  it exists  $β_2\in B_2$ such that $x\in β_2\subseteq β_1$

---

$(i)\Rightarrow (ii)$

Let $τ_1\subseteq τ_2$ and  $x\in β_1$, assume it doesn't exist such $β_2\in B_2$ such that $x\in β_2\subseteq β_1$,
because $β_1\in τ_1\subseteq τ_2 \Rightarrow β_1\in τ_2$, since $x\in β_1 \subseteq τ_2$ I can consider $β_2=β_1$, and I have a contradiction.

$(ii)\Rightarrow (i)$ since for every $x$ I can find an open $β_2$ such that $β_2\subseteq β_1 \Rightarrow \bigcup_iβ_{2_i}=β_1 \Rightarrow β_1 \in B_2 \Rightarrow B_1\subseteq B2$

I don't feel very confident about those arguments, can someone help to make the proof correct.

Comment: What is $\beta_{2_i}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos its the open sets of $B_2$ that contain the element $x$

Comment: (Ii) in essence says that each member of $B_1$ is $\tau_2$-open. It’s clear that this both follows from and implies the inclusion in (I).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*i*) $\implies$ *ii*):

Take $x\in X$ and $\beta_1\in B_1$ such that $x\in\beta_1$. Since $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$ and $B_1\subset\tau_1$, $\beta_1\in\tau_2$. So, take $\beta_2=\beta_1$ and you're done.

*ii*) $\implies$ *i*):

Take $\beta\in\tau_1$. For each $x\in\beta$, take $\beta_x\in\tau_2$ such that $x\in\beta_x$ and that $\beta_x\subset\beta$. Then$$\beta=\bigcup_{x\in\beta}\{x\}\subset\bigcup_{x\in\beta}\beta_x\subset\beta,$$and therefore $\beta=\bigcup_{x\in\beta}\beta_x\in\tau_2$. Since this take place for each $\beta\in\tau_1$, $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$.